# Why does GDAL Translate not create any output in batch mode?

Tags: qgis, gdal, modis

Has anyone tried using the Batch Mode function in GDAL translate - qgis2?  I can process files individually ok, in my case MODISA HDF files. But the batch mode does not seem to work.  Here is my set up parameters[image]

After hitting OK, I get a message instantly saying that the operation is complete, but there is nothing in the Output directory or anywhere else.

Also, oddly, when I process files individually, I've got the 'Load into canvas' option ticked, but I get an error saying that this failed.  Its not such a big deal because I can add it ok, but perhaps this is another bug.  Any suggestions welcome.  Thanks!

Forgot to say that I'm using Windows 7, qgis2.